# ReadTheDocs says: "Failed to checkout revision: master"

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm trying to set up readthedocs.org integration for a project that is on GitHub.  The builds on RTD keep failing with this error: "Failed to checkout revision: master"

This is confusing because the repo in question has no `master` branch -- it has a `main` branch though, and RTD should default to `main` for git repositories.

Here's the raw log:

```
[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2023-11-01T17:19:31.981021Z, end-time: 2023-11-01T17:19:32.374086Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/atlanticwave-sdx/sdx-docs .
Cloning into '.'...

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2023-11-01T17:19:32.394696Z, end-time: 2023-11-01T17:19:32.729551Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git fetch origin --force --prune --prune-tags --depth 50

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2023-11-01T17:19:32.809966Z, end-time: 2023-11-01T17:19:32.871692Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 1
git checkout --force master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

I can't seem to change the default branch, because the dropdown under admin > advanced settings > default branch is empty.

Things that are probably worth noting:

- On GitHub, the "Read the Docs Community" application has been granted permission to the org under which I have the problem repository.
- On RTD, "Integration - GitHub incoming webhook" has been set up, and as far as I can see, there are no errors. I tried adding and removing this hook, and resyncing the webhook, but that made no difference.

Why does RTD attemp to check out a non-existent `master` branch when there's a `main` branch? Can I change this behavior, and how?

Answer (score 1):

I no longer have this problem. I reached out to RTD support, and they solved this for me.

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).

Comment: Isn't the answer I wrote clear enough? People with the problem I described should reach out to official support.